# how to create a timer- and show it in the canvas

Tags: android, canvas, timer, bitmap

I got a canvas and bitmaps in the game that I build, and I wanted to add a timer.
However, all the tutorials that I saw used TextView. In my app, I can't see the TextView since I have a Canvas and Bitmaps above them.
How can I create a timer although this problem.
Thanks! This is the code:

```
while(pressed!=true){
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) 
                continue;
            Canvas c= holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawBitmap(galaxy, 30, 0, null);
            c.drawBitmap(player, x-(player.getWidth()/2), y-(player.getHeight()/2), null);
            c.drawText("2:34", 30, 60, timerpaint);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
```

Comment: Could you post your layout code?

Comment: read Canvas documentation, come back here if you have any problem with it

Comment: I looked over the internet and didn't find any information that I understood (English isn't my mother language, but not just because this). my layout (the xml) is empty, this is the line that draws over the screen:"
c.drawBitmap(galaxy, 30, 0, null);
    c.drawBitmap(player, x-(player.getWidth()/2), y-(player.getHeight()/2), null);"

should I use the "drawText(char[] text, int index, int count, float x, float y, Paint paint)" command?

Comment: any `drawText()` would be OK, choose the simplest one

Comment: Thanks!
But now any time I Bitmap picture, draw in the same x values of the text in the Canvas, she keeps drawing itself over the screen, although it shouldn't.

Comment: You need to make sure that the drawText() always is the last thing that you draw, so that it's on top. Each time you draw your bitmap, you need also to redraw the text.

Comment: I tried, but it still happened at the end of the screen(all the x that smaller then the place of the text) 
I added the code